# Est-ce un complément essentiel ?

Tags: grammaire, compléments

Dans la phrase

> Quand irez-vous **à la plage** ?

la partie en gras est-elle un complément essentiel (exercice de ce2) ?
J'ai du mal à trancher, car pour moi c'est un complément circonstanciel de lieu, donc a priori non essentiel, mais si on tente de l'enlever ou de le déplacer, la phrase devient très bizarre.

Comment: Il est essentiel en français, mais pas en anglais. Ca arrive assez souvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu as répondu à ta question.

Si on supprime *à la plage*, la phrase devient très bizarre. Il lui manque quelque chose... d'**essentiel** ! CQFD.